# yii two models in _form while using xupload, error undefined variable

Tags: php, yii, models, yii-xupload

```
 Controller : 
 Yii::import("xupload.models.XUploadForm"); //enciora
            $photos = new XUploadForm;
 $this->render('create', array(                    
                'model' => $model,
                'photos' => $photos
            ));

 create: <?php echo 
 $this->renderPartial('_form', 
    array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'photos' => $photos
        )); ?>

_form:  <?php
        $this->widget( 'xupload.XUpload', array(
            'url' => Yii::app()->createUrl( "/encionmentDetail/upload"),
            //our XUploadForm
            'model' => $photos,
            //We set this for the widget to be able to target our own form
            'htmlOptions' => array('id'=>'encionment-detail-form'),
            'attribute' => 'file',
            'multiple' => true,
            //Note that we are using a custom view for our widget
            //Thats becase the default widget includes the 'form' 
            //which we don't want here
            'formView' => 'application.views.encionmentDetail._form',
            )    
        );
        ?>
```

ERROR: Undefined variable: model or Undefined variable: photos . this are the errors coming
while creating. if one model is passed then it shows properly. Please help

Well, the problem is with this line 'formView' => 'application.views.encionmentDetail._form'

. if i remove this line then no error. what should i do ?

Comment: what's the content of `application.views.encionmentDetail._form`? Are you calling a variable in there that you've not passed through to it?

Comment: show where you create model and photos

Comment: Probably you are trying to display an attribute that's not defined in your model. For example $model->someAttribute, Where someAttribute is not an attribute of Model.

Answer (score 0):

This could well be due to the fact that your _form and your inner form for

```
'formView' => 'application.views.encionmentDetail._form',
```

are the same. Use a different one in the form view. Its kind of getting recursive.

Answer (score 0):

in controller file :-

```
<?php 
     Yii::import("xupload.models.XUploadForm"); 

     $photos = new XUploadForm;
     $this->render('create', array(                    

            'photos' => $photos,
     ));
?>
```

in create a file passing a bot model in render file :-

```
<?php echo $this->renderPartial('_form', array('model'=>$model,'photo'=>$photo))
```

Important note : **must same a active from id and extensition html option id**

Answer (score 0):

snow_walker absolutely right, but I want to give details.Well, maybe it will help someone.

Such case occurs when xupload widget view contains `<form>`, so when it renders it becomes nested in CActiveForm.

One of the way to fix it:

Place CActiveForm widget in **create.php**

Copy everything from standard xupload form view (…\protected\extensions\xupload\views\form.php) to your model _form.php  (…\protected\views\somemodel_form.php)

Delete from **_form.php**

```
<?php if ($this->showForm) echo CHtml::beginForm($this -> url, 'post', $this -> htmlOptions);?>
```

and

```
<?php if ($this->showForm) echo CHtml::endForm();?>
```

Answer (score -1):

The other thing is that you cannot change the attribute's value in the widget configuration. It has to be 'file' in the other way the Internal Server Error (500) occurs.

Comment: Why this is related with the question?